# EF5 Migrations Seed AddOrUpdate with a nullable selection criteria

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have a question to which someone may have found a solution in the past. I'm seeding the database in the Configuration class of EF5 migrations, using the AddOrUpdate method.

Here's the quick example of the domain model:

```
 public class Club
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Court
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual long? ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
}
```

Then here is an extract from my seed method:

```
Club cb = new Club { Name = "Test Club 1" };
context.Set<Club>().AddOrUpdate(m=>m.Name, cb);
context.SaveChanges();

Court crt1 = new Court { ClubId = cb.Id, Name = "Court 1" };
Court crt2 = new Court { ClubId = cb.Id, Name = "Court 2" };
context.Set<Court>().AddOrUpdate(m => new { m.Name, m.ClubId }, crt1, crt2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, once the code reaches line number 7, it throws an error:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]' and 'System.Int64'.

From my investigation it's due to the fact that ClubId is a Nullable long.

Is there any way around this?

Not a major issue - I'm just a perfectionist, and would like to see how others may have solved this...

Thanks,
Nick Goloborodko

Comment: Just to clarify - classes have more properties on them - but I've omitted them for clarity.

Comment: I had a similar issue. As workaround I switched to different parameter. So in this case I wouldn't be using m.ClubId at all, just m.Name

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a very satisfactory answer, but I believe that there would need to be a code change to the AddOrUpdate implementation to fix this so I have applied a workaround.

Simply put, rather than use `AddOrUpdate`, you do the same task manually. For example:

```
private void AddOrUpdateCourt(long id, string name, string someOtherPropertyValue)
{
    var court = _context.Set<Court>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id = id && c.Name = name);
    if(court == null)
    {
        _context.Set<Court>().Add(new Court
        {
            ClubId=id, 
            Name=name, 
            SomeOtherProperty = someOtherPropertyValue
        });
    }
    else
    {
        court.SomeOtherProperty = someOtherPropertyValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem, implemented my own `AddOrUpdate` in the end.

First, we have to get the actual primary keys of our entity (maybe you need to add additional naming conventions here...):

```
private static PropertyInfo[] PrimaryKeys<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class
{
    return typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
                          .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(KeyAttribute))
                                   || "Id".Equals(p.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                          .ToArray();
}
```

Then, we need to parse the "identifiers expression", which is used by `AddOrUpdate` to match  existing items (like the original `AddOrUpdate`):

```
private static PropertyInfo[] Properties<TEntity>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> identifiers)
    where TEntity : class
{
    // e => e.SomeValue
    var direct = identifiers.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (direct != null)
    {
        return new[] { (PropertyInfo)direct.Member };
    }

    // e => (object)e.SomeValue
    var convert = identifiers.Body as UnaryExpression;
    if (convert != null)
    {
        return new[] { (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)convert.Operand).Member };
    }

    // e => new { e.SomeValue, e.OtherValue }
    var multiple = identifiers.Body as NewExpression;
    if (multiple != null)
    {
        return multiple.Arguments
                       .Cast<MemberExpression>()
                       .Select(a => (PropertyInfo)a.Member)
                       .ToArray();
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Thus, `.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Name, ...)` should work as well as `.AddOrUpdate(m => new { m.Name, m.ClubId }, ...)`.

Finally, we build the *where expression* dynamically for every entity, match it with our current database, and act accordingly (add or update):

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(this DbContext context,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> identifiers,
    params TEntity[] entities)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var primaryKeys = PrimaryKeys<TEntity>();
    var properties = Properties<TEntity>(identifiers);

    for (var i = 0; i < entities.Length; i++)
    {
        // build where condition for "identifiers"
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        var matches = properties.Select(p => Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, p),
            Expression.Constant(p.GetValue(entities[i]), p.PropertyType)));
        var match = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            matches.Aggregate((p, q) => Expression.AndAlso(p, q)),
            parameter);

        // match "identifiers" for current item
        var current = context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(match);
        if (current != null)
        {
            // update primary keys
            foreach (var k in primaryKeys)
                k.SetValue(entities[i], k.GetValue(current));

            // update all the values
            context.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(entities[i]);

            // replace updated item
            entities[i] = current;
        }
        else
        {
            // add new item
            entities[i] = context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entities[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, although the question is a bit old.

Comment: I think that it would help me but I can't figure out how to call this instead of the original AddOrUpdate.

Comment: `context.AddOrUpdate<MyEntity>(e => e.Name, entities)` or `context.AddOrUpdate<MyEntity>(e => new { e.Some, e.Thing }, entities)`. It should work similar to the original AddOrUpdate(set, identifierExpression, entities), but its build for DbContext instead of DbSet (so you could use both).

Comment: Ah! missed the fact that it is built on DbContext. Thanks for the update.